# How to use exitHereIfFailed

Tags: scala, websocket, gatling

I have a scenario as following

```
foo=exec ()
    .exec()
    ...    //few more execs

wsOp=repeat(repeatCount){
    exec(
         ws("Send HeartBeat")
         .sendText("some Heartbeat format").exitHereIfFailed
    )
    exec(
         ws("Check HeartBeat")
         .check(wsAwait.within(500).until(1).regex("some regex"))).exitHereIfFailed
    )
    .pause(delay)
}
val foo=scenario("bar").exec(foo).exec(wsOp)
```

I have been trying to use gatling's exitHereIfFailed statement, but it doesnt work as I expect it to. In spite of the of the fact that a few ws operations in the ws send or the check fail, the user thread keeps executing the "wsOp".

Answer (score 4):

```
It should be after exec

foo=exec ()
    .exec()
    ...    //few more execs

wsOp=repeat(repeatCount){
    exec(
         ws("Send HeartBeat")
         .sendText("some Heartbeat format")
    ).exitHereIfFailed
    exec(
         ws("Check HeartBeat")
         .check(wsAwait.within(500).until(1).regex("some regex")))
    ).exitHereIfFailed
    .pause(delay)
}
val foo=scenario("bar").exec(foo).exec(wsOp)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, exitHereIfFailed is a structure DSL element (same level as exec), so it can be called on a ws action and your code doesn't even compile.

Then, there's a missing leading dot for exec(ws("Check HeartBeat")) so it's not chained with the previous exec, causing ws("Send HeartBeat") to be discarded.